# Combining CSS classes in an element

Tags: css

This could be the silliest question I've ever made, but why does the text below is not rendered red?

```
<html>
  <style>
  .c1 .c2 { 
     color: red; 
  }
  </style>
  <body>
     <span class="c1 c2">This should be red</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: I want to match elements that contain both c1 and c2 classes, like the example above, no less.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.c1 .c2` matches a c2 element inside a c1 element, just like `html body` matches a body element inside an html element. Remove the space to match an element with both classes:

```
.c1.c2 { 
   color: red; 
}
```

Comment: This style seems to match elements that only have class="c2" as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `.c1.c2`. The way you have it written is a `c2` INSIDE a `c1`.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.c1 .c2` really means an element with the class `c2` inside an element with the class `c1`.

To get the desired result, change your selector to `.c1.c2`, which will match elements with both styles.

Answer (score 1):

If the intended meaning of your CSS is to match “an element with both `c1` and `c2` in its list of classes”, then it sould be `.c1.c2`. The given selector (`.c1 .c2`) means “an element with the class `c2` that is a directly inside an element with the class `c1`”.

Edit: For sake of completeness, to match an element with at least one of the classes `c1` and `c2`, you would use `.c1, .c2`. So, the space refers to the structure of the document, no space is “and” and comma is “or”.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.c1 .c2` selects a `c2` element that is a child/descendant of a `c1` element.

What you want is:

```
c1,
c2 {color: red; }
```

In response to comment from OP

To target only elements with both classes:

```
c1.c2 {color: red; }
```

Comment: But I want to match only elements that have both c1 and c2 classes. Your style will match any c1 or c2, right?

Comment: @rodbv: That is right. You want the selector `.c1.c2` to match both classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma after .c1?

Comment: That would work to make this element red, but it seems that the intended meaning is to specify the rule for elements having *both* `c1` and `c2`, in which case it's `.c1.c2`.